# The meaning of "pure" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's "pure" means in the sentence below?

> There are many who must work out of **pure** economic necessity.

Comment: Please check a dictionary of your choice first.

Answer (score 2):

MW gives this definition:

> **2 a :** being thus and no other

I could see how that definition is a little hard to penetrate if you're not familiar with the idea already. The sentence could be reworded as,

> There are many who must work *for no other reason than* economic necessity.